# Angular Component with Content Projection Not Loading Properly in Storybook until a Control Is Changed

Tags: storybook, angular-storybook

I'm new to Storybook, and am having trouble getting components which project `ng-content` to correctly receive input arguments on initial load.

Template:

```html
<div id="alert-card">
    <div>
        <div class="iconDiv" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxLayoutGap="10px">

            <mat-icon *ngIf='this.alertType === "Warning"' class="warningIcon" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Warning">warning</mat-icon>
            <mat-icon *ngIf='this.alertType === "Error"' class="errorIcon" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Error">error</mat-icon>
            <mat-icon *ngIf='this.alertType === "Info"' class="infoIcon" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Info">info</mat-icon>
            <mat-icon *ngIf='this.alertType === "Confirm"' class="confirmIcon" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Confirm">check_circle</mat-icon>

            <span><span class="alertType">{{ alertKeyword }}</span>{{ alertMessage }} </span>
        </div>
        <ng-content select="[cardContent]"></ng-content>
    </div>
</div>
```

Component:

```js
import {
    Component,
    Input,
    ViewEncapsulation,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'alert-card',
    templateUrl: './alert-card.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./alert-card.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})

// Displays the alert card
export class AlertCardComponent {
    // The type of alert
    @Input()
    alertType: AlertType;
    
    // The keyword at the start of the alert message
    @Input()
    alertKeyword: string;

    // The alert message to display
    @Input()
    alertMessage: string;

    constructor() {}
}

// Indicates a type of alert which has an associated icon and color scheme in the CSS
export enum AlertType {
    Warning = "Warning",
    Error = "Error",
    Info = "Info",
    Confirm = "Confirm",
}
```

Story:

```js
import { componentWrapperDecorator, Meta, Story } from '@storybook/angular';
import { AlertCardComponent, AlertType } from './alert-card.component';

export default {
    component: AlertCardComponent,
    decorators: [componentWrapperDecorator(AlertCardComponent)],
} as Meta;

const Template: Story = (args) => ({
    props: args,
    template: `
        <div cardContent
        style="padding:10px"
        fxLayoutAlign="center">
            Arbitrary HTML content can go in this area
        </div>
        `
});

export const Warning = Template.bind({});
Warning.args= {
    alertType: AlertType.Warning,
    alertKeyword: "Warning: ",
    alertMessage: "something has happened!"
};
```

This is nearly working as expected, but within the story, the component loads without any of the input arguments: [image: Screenshot of component without any args passed as input]

If I change any of the Storybook controls, the input arguments are passed and the component displays as expected: [image]

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Everything works as expected once I start manipulating the controls within Storybook, but how do I get the input arguments passed on initial load?

I'm also having what I believe are related issues on Storybook's Docs page. The component is displayed as it would without any arguments passed regardless of how the inputs are controlled.

Comment: I had a similar problem, and was able to solve it by adding the inputs themselves to the template used by storybook. Maybe try adding `[alertType]="alertType" [alertKeyword]="alertKeyword" [alertMessage]="alertMessage"` to the template? So then the template would look like:  `<div cardContent style="padding:10px" fxLayoutAlign="center" [alertType]="alertType" [alertKeyword]="alertKeyword" [alertMessage]="alertMessage"> Arbitrary HTML content can go in this area </div>`